# Setting JLabel icon through code

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, embedded-resource

The following code will only work on my computer but not on others:

```
doll.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/akashsharma/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hangman/src/win/images/G.jpg"));
```

I have tried using the following but it results in a `NullPointerException`.

```
getClass().getResource("/images/G.jpg")
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

[The arrangement of files in the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oPQL.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Do you notice the difference between `../G.jpg` & `../G.png`? Try `/win/images/G.jpg` & if that doesn't work, describe the directory structure in the IDE, down to the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please show the stack trace and the line of code which causes the crash.

Comment: The path for getResource would need to be /win/images/G.jpg. Based on your current context, remember, the root search path starts from src

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry i mistyped the question it will be G.jpg and not G.png.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I followed your suggestion and now i am not getting a nullPointerException but still the icon is not being set.

Comment: @AkashSharma Then the image isn't where you think it is. Verify that the is stored in `win/images/G.jpg` within your project, make sure it's visible from within netbeans project, make sure you perform a clean and build. As a last resort, unzip the Jar file

Comment: @MadProgrammer https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oPQL.jpg

Comment: @Akash Sharma: You are referencing to your file with an absolute path. In your case "C:/Users/akashsharma/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Hangman/src/win/images/G.jpg". Are you sure, that the parent folders "/Users/akashsharma/Documents/NetBeansProjects/" exist on the "other" computers you want to run your program on? I strongly recommend to use relative paths, so that you're not dependend on the file structure outside/above your program's.

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"As a last resort, unzip the Jar file"* Good idea. I suspect Netbeans expects resources to go in a `resources` directory and won't include them in the Jar unless they are in that (or a sub-directory of it).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Unless it's a maven project, Netbeans won't (generally) care, but when you have problems, seeing what's in the Jar is always a good idea :P

Comment: @AkashSharma: Please have a look at [Loading Image Resource](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230). I hope it will be of some help on the topic :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it only works in your computer then it is a directory error.

Solution:

- Import the image to your project
- Use the following code

  ```
  jLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/FOLDER_NAME/G.jpg")));
  ```